# Consider a cube $c$ centered at origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The number of Invertible linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^3$ which map c onto itself

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a cube $c$ centered at origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The number of Invertible linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^3$ which map $c$ onto itself.

Comment: Make a cube out of paper and tape and try things! :-) All of your transformations are going to be isometries, so just rigid transformations of the cube that you can play with.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Your approach does not include reflections

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's true. But the subgroup of such transformations with determinant 1 is of order 2, so describing them is sufficient to understand the isometry group. And they can be understood very explicitly by playing with a cube box -- there's a perspective from which it is completely obvious that the number of determinant 1 transformations is 24, that I think someone will find if they think hard enough about what they are doing when they move the cube around.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $c$ is convex, so the image of $c$ under a linear transformation will be convex. With that in mind: where a linear transformation could send the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) (the corners) of $c$ so that the image of $c$ is a subset of $c$ *and* the image of $c$ contains all of $c$?

---

**Alternative approach:** The cube has four diagonals. I claim that a transformation that maps the cube to itself must map each diagonal to a diagonal, possibly "flipping" the endpoints of the diagonal.